# Returning char into main method

Tags: java, eclipse, string, methods, char

The goal of my program is kind of like wheel of fortune, a user will guess letters of a phrase. the letters will be revealed as guessed.  I am just starting, and having a problem returning a character into the main method.  I know there are other ways to make this program, but my professor wants us to use a "getguess"method. This method is supposed to take the users input and verify that it is a lowercase character.  For some reason i can not figure out how to do this. I have copied my program in with my attempt at the program.
Thanks,

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Program09 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
         String phrase;

         System.out.print("Enter a common phrase: ");
         phrase=stdIn.next();

         int sum=0; 
         getGuess(stdIn);
     }

     public static char getGuess(Scanner stdIn) {
         char LetterGuess;
         do{
             System.out.println("Guess a letter: ");
             LetterGuess=stdIn.next();
         } while(isLowerCase(LetterGuess) == false)

         return LetterGuess;
     }

}
```

Comment: Why are you passing stdIn as a parameter?

Comment: I think you should pass the String phrase as a parameter. In the getGuess method, convert the String to charArray. Post that ,

ask the user for a character, If the character exists in the phrase, return the positions of the respective character found in the charArray. This projects that you do not have to return a character from the function but you have to return an int[].

Also, In the main method the method getGuess should be called until the user either quits or reveals all the letters.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what all you need the program to do. I still feel confused. I think we can help better if you explain more about what do you expect this code to do !

Answer (score 1):

In your program you are returning the LetterGuess (which should start with a lowercase L) but in the main program you are not receiving it in any variable.

I think your first step shoul be to use something like:

```
char c = getGuess(stdIn);
System.out.println(c);
```

That for a starter, then you just have to make changes in the logic to read multiple guesses

Answer (score 0):

Try to think about it this way: a method is some block of computation that optionally takes in some input and optionally returns some output. We work with methods in real life all the time:

```
if(washing machine is available){
  washed_clothes = use_washing_machine(dirty_clothes)
  wait(40 minutes)
  dried_clothes = use_dryer(washed_clothes)
  clean clothes = fold(dried_clothes)
}
```

So, what you want to do is gather the user input in the `main` class, then pass it to the the `getGuess` method, which will do some computation (check if it's lower case), and then return a value back to `main`. You should return a `Boolean` data type ('true' or 'false') from `getGuess`, if you've learned about it.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, you should start your variable name with lowercase letter.
>   At your line where you get the char from console...

```
             LetterGuess=stdIn.next();
```

return a String, so you have to convert it to char...

```
             letterGuess=stdIn.next().trim().charAt(0);
```

and, in your while condition, line should be...

```
Character.isLowerCase(letterGuess) == false
```

> In your main method, save the returned char in a variable and then do what you want to do with that...